# How can Mathematica convert CMYK values to RGB or HSB?

Tags: color

```
cmyk = {{0., 0.05, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.1, 0., 0.2}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.},
        {0., 0.1, 0., 0.1}, {0., 0.15, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.07, 0., 0.07}, {0., 0.07, 0., 0.},
        {0., 0.02, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.1, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.3, 0., 0.}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.},
        {0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.}, {0., 0.25, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.2, 0., 0.1}, {0., 0.2, 0., 0.},
        {0., 0.2, 0., 0.2}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1},
        {0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2},
        {0.4, 0.55, 0.4, 0.}, {0., 0.2, 0., 0.4}};
```

I have tried quite a few things, but it seems there is an assumption the data is RGB even if there are 4 values in the array.

Comment: Have you tried the ColorConvert function?

Comment: 4 value `List` may leads to RGBA color instead of RGB, where the 4th number is used for the alpha channel.

Comment: @KAI Yes Certainly and the result is still a 4d array

Comment: @Silvia That's what I ran into also.

Comment: @RHall, please fix your code above, you are clearly missing a set of curly braces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rgb = ColorConvert[#, "CMYK" -> "RGB"] & /@ CMYKColor @@@ cmyk
ImageAssemble[{Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 20] & /@ 
Partition[Riffle[rgb, Rectangle[], {2, -1, 2}], 2]}]
```

[image: rgb colors]

Edit: to get raw values, use this additional line of code:

```
rgbValues = {##} & @@@ rgb
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, but produces an error on larger arrays. I just want the RGB values not a colored result.

Comment: {{RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], RGBColor[0., 0., 0.]}} the result produces this type of return, I need {{0., 0., 0.},{0., 0., 0.}} this type.

Comment: See edit, added this feature.

Comment: `rgbValues = List @@@ rgb` would be sufficient. (+1)

Comment: @R Hall how large is your array that causes problems, and what does the error message say exactly?

Comment: @shrx Done! Thanks and +1 for Silvia for the slick finish!  Seems like this kind of color conversion should be just as straight forward as the rest, but clearly it is not.

Comment: Well the conversion from RGB to CMYK is pretty straightforward: `RGBToCMY[RGBColor[r_, g_, b_]] := CMYKColor[1 - r, 1 - g, 1 - b, 0]`. See more [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CMYKColor.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `ColorSpace` option of `ColorConvert` to tell it how to interpret the input data. This allows you to go directly from raw data to raw data, without the `CMYKColor` and `RGBColor` heads:

```
rgb = ColorConvert[#, "RGB", ColorSpace -> "CMYK"] & /@ cmyk

(* {{1., 0.95, 1.}, {0.8, 0.72, 0.8}, {0.81, 0.72, 0.81}, {0.9, 0.8, 0.9} ... *)
```

Comment: `ColorConvert[#, "CMYK" -> "RGB"] & /@ cmyk` also works.